# What is the Android Play Services SDK level?

Tags: android

I am trying to do something with the [Android Face API](https://developers.google.com/vision/), but my phone does not detect faces on a simple example.

In Pre-requisites, I found that it needs: 
"Android Play Services SDK level 26 or greater", but the API number, 26, does not exist, so what is **"Android Play Services SDK level 26"**?

Answer (score 6):

Don't be confused between the Google Play Services SDK and Android API level.
The latest Google Play Service is now using the 26th SDK version and the latest Android API is the 23rd (Android marshmallow).

Edit:
You can find the Google Play services SDK number into the SDK manager. 
Currently the version 8.3 is using the SDK 28.